# Comparing scipy.stats.t.sf vs GSL using Cython

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cython, gsl

I would like to calculate the p values of a large 2D numpy t values array. However, this takes long time and I would like to improve its speed. I tried using GSL. 
Although a single gsl_cdf_tdist_P is much much faster than scipy.stats.t.sf, when iterating over the ndarray, the process is very slow. I would like help to improve this. 
See the code below.

GSL_Test.pyx

```
import cython
cimport cython

import numpy
cimport numpy
from cython_gsl cimport *

DTYPE = numpy.float32
ctypedef numpy.float32_t DTYPE_t

cdef get_gsl_p(double t, double nu):
    return (1 - gsl_cdf_tdist_P(t, nu)) * 2

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
cdef get_gsl_p_for_2D_matrix(numpy.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] t_matrix, int n):

    cdef unsigned int rows = t_matrix.shape[0]
    cdef numpy.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] out = numpy.zeros((rows, rows), dtype='float32')
    cdef unsigned int row, col

    for row in range(rows):
        for col in range(rows):
            out[row, col] = get_gsl_p(t_matrix[row, col], n-2)
    return out

def get_gsl_p_for_2D_matrix_def(numpy.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] t_matrix, int n):
    return get_gsl_p_for_2D_matrix(t_matrix, n)
```

ipython

```
import GSL_Test
import numpy
import scipy.stats
a = numpy.random.rand(3544, 3544).astype('float32')
%timeit -n 1 GSL_Test.get_gsl_p_for_2D_matrix(a, 25)
1 loop, best of 3: 7.87 s per loop
%timeit -n 1 scipy.stats.t.sf(a, 25)*2
1 loop, best of 3: 4.66 s per loop
```

**UPDATE:** Adding cdef declarations I was able to  reduce the computational time but not lower than scipy still. I modified the code to have the cdef declarations.

```
%timeit -n 1 GSL_Test.get_gsl_p_for_2D_matrix_def(a, 25)
1 loop, best of 3: 6.73 s per loop
```

Comment: What do you know about `stats.t.sf`?  Why do you think a `cython` version can be faster?  I look for things like iterations that can be translated to `c`.

Comment: scipy.stats.t.sf and other methods have some python overhead mainly for input checking. If you want speed, then you can use the scipy.special functions directly which are written either in Fortran or in C. I doubt it's possible to beat scipy.special by any sizable amount unless there is a more efficient algorithm or an algorithm that trades off speed for accuracy.

Comment: There's  no advantage to having a separate `def` and `cdef` function for get_gsl_p_for_2D_matrix. You might get a bit from specifying a return type for get_gsl_p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get some small gain in raw performance by using a raw special function instead of `stats.t.sf`. Looking at the source, you find  (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py#L3849)

```
def _sf(self, x, df):
      return sc.stdtr(df, -x)
```

So that you can use `stdtr` directly:

```
np.random.seed(1234)
x = np.random.random((3740, 374))
t1 = stats.t.sf(x, 25)
t2 = stdtr(25, -x)

1 loop, best of 3: 653 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 562 ms per loop
```

If you do reach out for cython, the typed memoryview syntax often gives you faster code than the old ndarray syntax:

```
from scipy.special.cython_special cimport stdtr
from numpy cimport npy_intp
import numpy as np

def tsf(double [:, ::1] x, int df=25):
    cdef double[:, ::1] out = np.empty_like(x)
    cdef npy_intp i, j
    cdef double tmp, xx

    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        for j in range(x.shape[1]):
            xx = x[i, j]
            out[i, j] = stdtr(df, -xx)

    return np.asarray(out)
```

Here I'm also using the `cython_special` interface, which is only avaialble in the dev version of scipy (http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/special.cython_special.html#module-scipy.special.cython_special), but you can use GSL if you want.

Finally, if you suspect a bottleneck in iterations, don't forget to inspect the output of `cython -a` to see if there's some python overhead in the hot loops.